# Substitution in parameters to "Which"

Tags: syntax

Why in this expression

```
In[1]:= a = 1;
b = 2;
f[x_] := Which[x < a, 10, a <= x < b, 20, True, 30]
f[x]

Out[4]= Which[x < 1, 10, a <= x < b, 20, True, 30]
```

the values of `a` and `b` are substituted only in the first parameter to `Which` and not in the third?

I am using Mathematica 8 on OSX.

Comment: Can't try it but probably because this is the place where evaluation had to stop since `x<1` does not return `True/False`. The `out[4]` is unevaluated form of expression with this first step done.

Comment: See "Details" section of [doc](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Which.html) of `Which`. Especially the second item.

Comment: If you want your parameter values to show up in all tests for symbolic values of x, use `Piecewise` rather than `Which`. `f[x_] = Piecewise[{{10, x < a}, {20, a <= x < b}}, 30]`

Comment: Thanks @Naitree and Kuba, I realized my mistake.  The problem now is how to Plot a similar function, given that Plot does not seem collaborative, but this is probably matter for another question.

Comment: @BobHanlon: ok, with `Piecewise`
 I can Plot the function.

Comment: One useful function here is `TrueQ` too.

Answer (score 2):

So, this is the case I've anticipated and Nitree pointed out in comments:

> If any of the *test_i* evaluated by Which give neither `True` nor `False`, then a `Which` object containing these remaining elements is returned unevaluated.

This is clearly shown by:

```
Which[    a, 1 + 1,     False, 1 + 1,     False, 1 + 1]
Which[False, 1 + 1,         a, 1 + 1,     False, 1 + 1]
Which[False, 1 + 1,     False, 1 + 1,         a, 1 + 1]
```

> ```
> Which[a, 1 + 1, False, 1 + 1, False, 1 + 1]
> Which[a, 1 + 1, False, 1 + 1]
> Which[a, 1 + 1]
> ```

So since you are providing symbolic `x` with not value attached, first test returns `x<1` which is neither `True` nor `False`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Clear[a, x]

a = 0;

Which[
 x < a, 1,
 x > a, 2,
 x == a, 3]
```

> Which[x < 0, 1, x > a, 2, x == a, 3]

According to the documentation, [`Which`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Which.html) has attribute `HoldAll`, except, apparently, for the first test!

(As demonstrated, `a` evaluates to zero in the first test.)

Comment: source? proof? :) Could you try something like `Which[False, 0, x < a, 10, a <= x < b, 20, True, 30]` ? I don't have mma around so I can't.

Comment: @Kuba - Initial `False` tests are dropped out immediately, e.g. `Which[False, 1, False, 2, x < a, 3, x > a, 4, False, 5]` - then `a` is again only evaluated in the first (remaining) test.