# How to have default case in Which?

Tags: functions, function-construction

Saying we have a function:

```
a[x_] := Which[x === 1, "AAA", x === 2, "BBB", _, $Failed]
```

How can I make this function to be equal to `$Failed` instead of `Which[_, $Failed]` when `x` is neither `1` or `2`?

Thanks!

Comment: Use `True` instead of `_`. p.s. in your case, `Switch` is more appriopriate.

Comment: I already have this Which in a big Switch

Comment: Ok, so as I said, use `True`. p.s. `a` returns what it returns because of incorrect statement you put there: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/71500/5478

Comment: I think it is easy to find in docs. Which/Details/ *3rd bullet point*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The symbol `_` is a shortcut for `Blank[]`. If you try evaluating

```
Blank[] === True
```

your result will be `False`, so your third condition can never be met. If you need an expression for your third condition that will always evaluate to `True`, I can think of a good one that works pretty well:

```
Which[
 x === 1, "AAA",
 x === 2, "BBB",
 True, $Failed
]
```